# How to retrieve attachment name and size using Google email audit API?

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk, google-email-audit-api

I have a code in Java used for email auditing. I do receive mails that are monitored. I am only requesting for HEADERS and what I really want is the attachment name and size, if any. But I am not getting this information in the headers. Any settings required to get this information?

Comment: As per my knowledge, If you use HEADER_ONLY, you cannot get all the details from the request. In order to get all the details of the email, you have to give FULL_MESSAGE in the request. Refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#creating_a_new_email_monitor) for more details. Hope that helps!

Comment: above comment is correct, should be made into an answer.